# How to identify computer using JS in a controlled environment

Tags: javascript, cookies, printing, local-storage, identifier

We have a warehouse with two printing hubs at different locations, nearby workstations. The users can be at either location, depending on what they are doing. Currently, I print at a given printing hub based on the action the user. However, I want to start printing to the closest printing hub.

So in order to send to the correct printing queue, I need to know which computer sent the request to print. Unfortunately, I can not tie the printer hub to the user. The computers will not be moved so we can map them to a printing hub.

[image: Existing Setup]

That being said, what are my options to identify a computer reliably (on frontend) when I have control to setup anything on those computers? The only option I came up with is to set a local storage variable with a very long expiry - however, I think that is prone to user clearing the local storage and therefore not reliable.

Comment: The only way out I see is at the server's side. The server could leverage knowledge of the client's IP Adress and map that to a printer. Depending on how funky you want to get you could go from a static mapping up to more sophisticated methods of guessing. But this is not a clear answer - so I leave it here as a comment.

Comment: That could work! However, computers need to be using different public and static IPs. Unfortunately, they share the same public IP and I don't think it's static.

Comment: You can append some kind of ID to the user-agent on startup of the browser. Then you can check for that ID to identify the computer. If you can't rely on users clicking on a dedicated startup shortcut then you can install an extension (at least for chromium and firefox browsers) that can append strings to user-agents.

Comment: Extension does sound reasonable and reliable option. I would need to disable all other browsers then as we are running a policy to always run latest stable chrome on those computers.